# socket.io: emit a message from the server to the server (!)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I can happily send messages to the clients from the server and also to the server from the clients.  I, however, seem to need to send (broadcast) **messages to the (server) sockets from the server itself** -- and I don't know how to go about it.

The case is that the server learns (via a Redis subscription) that a subset of the possibly very numerous clients need to be sent a message.  Each server side socket can determine on its own if it needs to fire or not.  I just don't know how to let them know they have to do the check (possibly in much the same way as 'normally' by a message from the client (?)).

FWIW the check can be made by using the handshakeData only (and other non-socket-instance-specific server side structures).  If there's a way to get to the handshakeData 'from the outside', it's also a possibility; but by no means really pretty.

Any thoughts/pointers anyone?

Comment: You could probably use the `socket.io-client` module to connect to localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have got it finally (by debugging the socket.io code).

Within a message handler fetch the socket in question and have a 'params' array set with the event and other attributes (usually a 'data' object with additional info).  With these two call `socket.$emit.apply(socket, params)`.

In actual code:

```
for (var socketId in io.namespaces['/mynamespace'].sockets) {
    var socket = io.namespaces['/mynamespace'].sockets[socketId];
    var params = ['test event', {'foo': 'bar'}];
    socket.$emit.apply(socket, params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I had a similar problem, I figured out there would be a standard nodeJS-specific solution. I found the `EventEmitter`:

http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter